# Cannot create proxy in jboss 5.0.1

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am using JBoss server 5.0.1 and have written a web service client using jax-rpc. I get the following exception when I run it. Since the JBoss web service is not accepting user defined Java beans to be passed in/out of jax-rpc, I have converted all of the Java beans objects into Strings, String arrays and primitive data types. So I invoke the web service from my client, but when I try to call my web service it throws the following exception. Please help me.

```
 17:27:09,537 ERROR [ServiceProxy] Service error
   javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: Cannot create proxy
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:359)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:127)
    at $Proxy105.getCarrierWSSEIPort(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot synchronize to any of these methods:
 public abstract java.lang.String[] client.CarrierWSSEI.getGroupID() throws java.rmi.RemoteException
 public abstract boolean client.CarrierWSSEI.checkRateData(java.lang.String) throws java.rmi.RemoteException
 public abstract boolean client.CarrierWSSEI.commitZipImportData(java.lang.String) throws java.rmi.RemoteException

 OperationMetaData:
  qname={urn:CarrierWS/wsdl}checkPlanData2
  javaName=checkPlanData
  style=document/literal/WRAPPED
  oneWay=false
  soapAction=
  ParameterMetaData:
  xmlName={urn:CarrierWS/types}checkPlanData2
  partName=checkPlanData2
  xmlType={urn:CarrierWS/types}checkPlanData2
  javaType=test.CarrierWSSEI_checkPlanData2_RequestStruct
  mode=IN
  inHeader=false
  index=0
  wrappedParameters=[[name = String_1, type = java.lang.String, typeArgs = null, variable = String_1, index = 0], [name = String_2, type = java.lang.String,         typeArgs = null, variable = String_2, index = 1]]
   ReturnMetaData:
   xmlName={urn:CarrierWS/types}checkPlanData2Response
   partName=checkPlanData2Response
   xmlType={urn:CarrierWS/types}checkPlanData2Response
   javaType=test.CarrierWSSEI_checkPlanData_ResponseStruct1
   mode=OUT
   inHeader=false
   index=-1
   wrappedParameters=[[name = result, type = boolean, typeArgs = null, variable = result, index = -1]]
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.OperationMetaData.eagerInitialize(OperationMetaData.java:491)
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.eagerInitializeOperations(EndpointMetaData.java:557)
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.initializeInternal(EndpointMetaData.java:541)
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.setServiceEndpointInterfaceName(EndpointMetaData.java:220)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:345)
         ... 33 more
 17:27:09,646 ERROR [STDERR] javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: Cannot create proxy
 17:27:09,646 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:359)
 17:27:09,646 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 17:27:09,646 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 17:27:09,646 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 17:27:09,646 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 17:27:09,646 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:127)
 17:27:09,646 ERROR [STDERR]     at $Proxy105.getCarrierWSSEIPort(Unknown Source)
 17:27:09,646 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:88)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
 17:27:09,662 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 17:27:09,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
 17:27:09,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
 17:27:09,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
 17:27:09,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
 17:27:09,677 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 17:27:09,677 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot synchronize to any of these methods:
 public abstract java.lang.String[] client.CarrierWSSEI.getGroupID() throws java.rmi.RemoteException
 public abstract boolean client.CarrierWSSEI.checkRateData(java.lang.String) throws java.rmi.RemoteException
 public abstract boolean client.CarrierWSSEI.commitZipImportData(java.lang.String) throws java.rmi.RemoteException
OperationMetaData:
qname={urn:CarrierWS/wsdl}checkPlanData2
javaName=checkPlanData
style=document/literal/WRAPPED
oneWay=false
soapAction=
ParameterMetaData:
 xmlName={urn:CarrierWS/types}checkPlanData2
 partName=checkPlanData2
 xmlType={urn:CarrierWS/types}checkPlanData2
 javaType=test.CarrierWSSEI_checkPlanData2_RequestStruct
 mode=IN
 inHeader=false
 index=0
 wrappedParameters=[[name = String_1, type = java.lang.String, typeArgs = null, variable = String_1, index = 0], [name = String_2, type = java.lang.String,        typeArgs = null, variable = String_2, index = 1]]
 ReturnMetaData:
 xmlName={urn:CarrierWS/types}checkPlanData2Response
 partName=checkPlanData2Response
 xmlType={urn:CarrierWS/types}checkPlanData2Response
 javaType=test.CarrierWSSEI_checkPlanData_ResponseStruct1
 mode=OUT
 inHeader=false
 index=-1
wrappedParameters=[[name = result, type = boolean, typeArgs = null, variable = result, index = -1]]
17:27:09,756 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.OperationMetaData.eagerInitialize(OperationMetaData.java:491)
17:27:09,756 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.eagerInitializeOperations(EndpointMetaData.java:557)
17:27:09,756 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.initializeInternal(EndpointMetaData.java:541)
17:27:09,756 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.setServiceEndpointInterfaceName(EndpointMetaData.java:220)
17:27:09,756 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:345)
17:27:09,756 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 33 more
```

The JSP client code is as follows:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Hashtable"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.*,javax.xml.rpc.Stub,stubs.CarrierWS,stubs.CarrierWSSEI,stubs.CarrierWSSEI_Impl"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<% try {
      InitialContext ic = new InitialContext( );
      CarrierWS carrierws = (CarrierWS)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/service/CarrierWS");
      out.println("========================" + carrierws);
      CarrierWSSEI sei = carrierws.getCarrierWSSEIPort();
      out.println("Invoking the service please wait ............." + carrierws.getCarrierWSSEIPort());
      ((Stub)sei)._setProperty(Stub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"http://localhost:8080/TestWS3WAR/CarrierWS");
      out.println("Invoking the service please wait ............." + sei.getActiveBenData().length);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      out.println("Exception occurred : " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
%>
</body></html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Senthil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that though I converted all the return types to String type the Jboss 5.0.1 GA does not method polymorphism in the web service interface and implementations.